# Calculate degree of a number over Q

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $p_{1},p_{2},p_{3},q_{1},q_{2},q_{3}$are distinct primes integer and $\alpha=q_{1}^{\frac1p_{1}}+q_{2}^{\frac1p_{2}}+q_{3}^{\frac1p_{3}}$ . Calculate $deg (\alpha)$ over Q rationals.

This is the problme I want to prove. I guess the degree is $p_{1}p_{2}p_{3}$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: That element is contained in an extension generated by three numbers, the three summands. Can you compute the degree of *that* extension?

Comment: That degree is q1q2q3 but I'm wandering the extension you said is same as  Q adjoing alpha over Q

Comment: In last lecture, I learned that degree of alpha is same as the order of orbit of alpha over a galois group of any polynomial which has alpha as a root. So I have tried to find polynomial that has alpha as a root. But i failed. Is that approach wrong?

Comment: What is the Galois group  of the extension I mentioned?

Comment: Z/p_{1}Z ×Z/p_{2}Z× Z/p_{3}Z isn't it?

Comment: A duplicate of [a recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1539398/11619). Somehow it feels likely that the questions are coming from students taking the same course (rolls eyes).